# Convergence of polynomials: Is my answer right?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, convergence-divergence

I would like to know if my solution to this problem makes sense or if you would solve it differently. I apologize for my English if anything is misspelled. I am not an english speaker. Thanks in advance for feedback.

Problem:

Consider the set $\mathbf{P}_m$ of all polynomials with real coefficients of degree n ≤ m, m ∈ N on [0, 1]. Let $(P_n)_{n∈\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of $\mathbf{P}_m$ that converges uniformly to a function F ∈ C([0, 1], $\mathbb{R}$). Prove that F is also a polynomial of degree n ≤ m.

Answer:

Because of the uniform convergence there exists an N with
$\vert P_m(x) - P_n(x)\vert$ < 1 for all m, n $\ge$ N and all x ∈ $\mathbb{R}$.
Consequently, all differences $P_m(x)-P_n(x)$ for m, n $\ge$ N are restricted to all $\mathbb{R}$ and, because they are polynomials, must be constant.
So there is a sequence of numbers $c_n$, defined for n $\ge$ N such that $P_n(x)=P_N(x)$ + $c_n$ holds for all n $\ge$ N and all x ∈ $\mathbb{R}$.
The uniform convergence of the sequence $P_n(x)$ now leads to the fact that this sequence of numbers is a Cauchy sequence and therefore has a limit c. The limit function P(x) is then equal to $P_N(x)$ + c, thus a polynomial, which was to be shown.

Comment: A polynomial being bounded by $1$ on $[0,1]$ does not imply that it is a constant. Example: $\frac x 2$

Answer (score 1):

Any finite dimensional subspace of $C[0,1]$ is complete. The space of polynomials with degree $\leq m$ is a  finite dimensional subspace. Hence the limit of $(P_n)$'s belongs to this space.